# change variable output in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables

I have a bash script that contains the following text:

```
LOAD=`/usr/bin/w |grep "load average"`
echo $LOAD
```

when I execute the script it searches for load average in the files inthe directory that is given. After it's executed the output is the following:

**10:06:40 up 7 days, 17:21, 3 users, load average: 0.08, 0.06, 0.09**

What I want is the $LOAD variable to give the following output:

**10:06:40 up 7 days, 17:21, 3 users, load averages: 0.08, 0.06, 0.09**

I can't recompile the files in the directory that is given so that is not an option. Any ideas how I am able to achieve this output?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting. What OS are you using? It already says 'load averages' on OSX.

Comment: You think it's a good idea to have your script *change* the output of a system command in a subtle way?

Comment: @Darragh Interesting, `load average` with `w` from `procps 3.2.8` on Ubuntu. Same on Gentoo from `procps-ng 3.3.2`.

Comment: @Darragh: "average" on SLES 10 and AIX 6.1 as well as the ones Adrian mentioned. If it's really "averages" on OS X, I'd call that an error, because it's the *one* load average of the system, sampled over different time frames - but the system only ever has that one, because it's the average... no?

Comment: @DevSolar Well, even the `procps` `uptime` man page talks about `load averages` and I'd also argue that three distinct values are different averages, even if they are based on the same input.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: Still, I'd rather go with whatever the system generates than modifying it in such ways. Imagine what happens when someone has written a follow-up script that does `grep "load average:"` because that's what worked with `w` before... but not with OP's script because he tinkered with the output. Ta-daaa...

Comment: [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-56/w/w.c) is the source code for Apple's `w`, it does print `averages`. This is stone-old `BSD` code, for what it's worth.

Comment: @DevSolar I agree and disagree, as you can see there are different implementations and those tools are not part of POSIX so whichever hypothetical script relies on a specific output (singular *or* plural) is broken in the first place. Other `BSD`s probably also use the plural so it's as "correct" as the `procps` implementation.

Comment: @DevSolar I checked the source code for both `NetBSD`'s as well as `OpenBSD`'s `w` implementation and both print `averages`. Not saying you are wrong in saying that you should generally avoid doing things like this (this is where I totally agree), but given that the `BSD` code is way older than the Linux `procps` implementation it's definitely not wrong and both are in use today. TL;DR: Don't rely on either when parsing `w`'s output, if you do your script is not portable and broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you just want to change "average" to "averages"?

```
echo "$LOAD" | sed 's/average/averages/'
```

Answer (score 1):

See [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). This replaces the first occurance of `average` with `averages`:

```
echo "${LOAD/average/averages}"
```